# Eclipse SWT - How to convert from 'id' to a usable type

Tags: java, objective-c, ios, serialization

I'm trying to create an Android client for a client/server app that has previously only supported iPhone-based clients.  The server was not really designed with the intention of supporting other devices, and some of the data I need to be able to process is stored as a chunk of bytes that was generated by using an `NSKeyedArchiver` to serialize an `NSDictionary` on the iPhone client.

To handle the deserialization I'm trying to use the Eclipse SWT, which includes Java bindings for Cocoa API calls and classes, including `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.  These seem to be working, but `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData()` returns an `id` type, and I haven't been able to figure out how to convert it into something usable (it should actually be an `NSDictionary`).  Obviousing in objective-c a simple cast would do the trick, but attempting the same in Java throws a `ClassCastException` at runtime:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.id cannot be cast to
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSDictionary

The code I am testing with is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    NSAutoreleasePool pool = (NSAutoreleasePool)new NSAutoreleasePool().alloc().init();

    //read the test data into a byte array
    int read = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(INPUT);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        bytes.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    buffer = bytes.toByteArray();

    System.out.println("Read " + buffer.length + " bytes");

    //load the byte array into an NSData instance
    NSData data = NSData.dataWithBytes(buffer, buffer.length);

    //deserialize the data              
    id result = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data);

    //error here
    NSDictionary dictionaryResult = (NSDictionary)result;

    pool.release();
}
```

So what do I need to do to convert 'result' from `id` to something more useful, like `NSDictionary`?

Comment: Did it actually work when executing this code on an Android Device? From what I was understanding, SWT uses an Java<->Objective C bridge to execute this code.

Comment: @grundprinzip - No, it won't work on an Android device.  In fact, I'm pretty sure this code will only properly work on a Mac.  Regardless, the way I'm using it is that a Mac server runs the SWT code on the app's server-side database.  It processes the native-iOS data structures, translates them to JSON, and then stores the JSON in the database.  The Android client downloads the JSON data, and all is well.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, I need to read and write to NSKeyedArchiver, please can you provide me with a few steps you took to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah, nevermind, I figured it out.  The way to get from `id` to something usable in SWT is to construct a new instance of the desired concrete type, passing the `id` as a parameter to the constructor.  Like:

```
NSDictionary dictionaryResult = new NSDictionary(result);
```

Obvious enough, when you think about it.